# python set operations on custom classes - union definition / lookup

Tags: python

Having a class with overridden `__eq__` and `__hash__` method I use sets for easy lookups (has also other reasons).

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.value == other.value

    def __hash__(self):
        return self.value

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.name, self.value)

mylist = [Foo(None, 1), Foo(None, 2), Foo(None,3)]
reference = [Foo("a", 1), Foo("b", 2), Foo("c", 3)]
```

Apparently python uses the first set when I perform operations like a union for the result set:

```
print(set(mylist) | set(reference)) # {None 1, None 2, None 3}
print(set(reference) | set(mylist)) # {a 1, b 2, c 3}
```

I could not find any documentation on this behaviour.

Is there a formal definition for this?
Or is it just undefined which set the interpreter takes on `union`s?

**EDIT** To make it clear:

A union on two sets is mathematically a symmetric operation, the behavior here is not symmetric. Can I rely on it?

Answer (score -1):

I think the answer is in your class definition.

`__eq__` checks for value equality, while `__hash__` returns a value. As a result, when sets are unified, the elements of one set are equal to their counterparts of the other set (respective values are equal), which causes the unified set return the first specified set.

Comment: If it was really about the class definition of mine:

1. How would I turn around this behaviour?

Comment: Ensure that equality AND hash comparisons are not bound to the same value. E.g. use `id(self)` for your `__hash__` implementation.

Comment: 2. Who says that on checking for equality (which is symmetric) the next interpreter version will not take the element from the other set?

in general:
A union is a symmetric operation (from the mathematical definition). Apparently it is not symmetric in python

Comment: Could you please bring a minimal example to your thesis? With a defined behaviour?
By that I mean a `__hash__` and/or `__eq__` function that would return the second set's elements

Comment: Ok, I will try. `__eq__` and `__hash__` implementations are both used for equality checks in a union operation. That means that if an element from one set has an equal (in your case, with same value) counterpart in the other set, that equal counterpart is not included in the united set. Try just changing the `__hash__` implementation as I suggested above: this should allow to return all six instances in the united set.

Comment: If I would change the `__hash__` implementation according to your suggestion, I would not have a lookup at all, it would just give me a set with all the 6 elements and not the second set

Comment: You have six separate instances of a class. If you need to overwrite the attributes of one set of instances based on the attributes of the other set of instances, union operations do not work this way as far as I know.

Comment: Yes they do, see the results. The script that is there as the example performs exactly that: It makes a lookup for the first list on the second list and returns a looked up list.

Comment: No, it returns a collection of unique objects. Since each object in the first passed set ('mylist' OR 'reference') has its duplicate in the other set (the script thinks so because you defined `__eq__` and `__hash__` respectively), only the first passed set is returned, and the objects from the other set are ignored.

Comment: Yes, but that is exactly the question: Where is it defined that on the union of two sets python will take the first one if there are equal elements in the second set?

Or In other words: can a rely on the fact that a mathematically symmetric operation (union) will remain antisymmetric like it is in the example or not?

Comment: 1. Union operation: "Returns a new set with elements from the set and the specified iterables." (Python reference).

Comment: 2. "An object is hashable if it has a hash value which never changes during its lifetime (it needs a `__hash__()` method), and can be compared to other objects (it needs an `__eq__()` or `__cmp__()` method). Hashable objects which compare equal must have the same hash value. Hashability makes an object usable as a dictionary key and a set member, because these data structures use the hash value internally." (Python Glossary)

Comment: What I am trying to explain to you is that the union operation returns a new set compiled from the two evaluated sets. If set 1 has elements a, b, c that are equal to elements d, e, f of set 2, then set 1 is returned because when an element has a duplicate (a-d, b-e, c-f), the duplicate is ignored. However, if set 1 included also an element X, and set 2 included an element Y, then the resulting union set would be a, b, c, X, Y.

Answer (score -1):

You're **eq** method implementation is based only on 'value' property

Changing it to the following implementation should solve the problem:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return (self.value == other.value) and (self.name == other.name)
```

Comment: What problem would it solve?
The `eq` method is based on value only on purpose. Otherwise no lookup for the name would be performed